# Where are the stories of Chandravali and Ayan found?

Tags: krishna, radha

Where is the story of Radha’s cousin named Chandravali, and childhood friend and lover named Ayan found?

Comment: Story of Radha and Ayan (Rayan) is found in Brahmavaivarta Purana which is discussed in [Was Radha aunt of Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31808/12304) post...

Comment: But Ayan was not yashoda's brother he was son of ugrapat and jatila from Barsana.

Comment: I don't know. Why are you questioning back?

Comment: Bcz, Abhimanyu, Ayan, Rayan, cousin/real brother of Yashoda, Jatila's son all are same..how you can say with full confidence that Jatila's son can't be Yasoda's cousin/real brother..?

Comment: Cz Ayan is same age as Krishna and jatila and Yashoda never met before .

Comment: from where you r telling these things...new tv show 'RadhaKrishn'??

Comment: Yes, I like how they have reason for everything but somehow I believe and not believe at the same time so I want to know from where all this coming,are all this true /imagination/ literature or what? There are always argument between me and others nether I nor they have any proof that it's true or not and I have a point that if all this false then give me that in which there is the full story?